# Groovy Create a File with current build Path?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

**EDIT**

I am trying to build a file in the current build directory.  Taking the build environment variables I created a string and attempted to create a new file with it.  However when I do this, I get errors "No such property"

```
String jobDir = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\${env.JOB_NAME}\\builds\\${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\\"
String FILEDIR = jobDir+"SOTR.log"
@Field File outFile = new File(FILEDIR)
```

I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class WorkflowScript. Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FILEDIR for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:466)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:430)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:393)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:238)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: FILEDIR for class: WorkflowScript
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307)
    at WorkflowScript.<init>(WorkflowScript:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:434)
    ... 7 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: If you are deploying, use absolte path. If you are building and need a relative path of the build directory, try out $WORKSPACE environment variable. cd %WORKSPACE%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you have used `@Field` annotation with variable `outFile` - when you do so it moves this variable from local scope to a script class scope. And because you refer to a local scope variable `FILEDIR` it throws `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` because there is no such field at the class level. Remove `@Field` annotation or add it to all other variables if this is your intention.

Also you can build your `jobDir` variable as:

```
String jobDir = "${env.JENKINS_HOME}\\jobs\\${env.JOB_NAME}\\builds\\${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Also keep in mind that by default Jenkins does not allow to use `java.io.File` class and if you didn't permit your server to do so you will get exception like:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String
```

Comment: So it would seem it is not possible to create a script class scope File, using environment variables?  I added the @Field before the jobDir and FILEDIR as well, and it did not work.  I have enabled the java.io.File class.
Thank you for the help and your suggestion to use JENKINS_HOME, makes sense.

Comment: I found it useful to add a new global property for this (in Manage Jenkins  → Configure System → Global Properties): `CURRENT_BUILD_PATH=$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/$JOB_NAME/builds/$BUILD_NUMBER`